# How do you setup the firestore rules with a custom authentication token, and then how do you connect with the token in Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to setup the security rules and also connect to the firestore database with a custom token. The token is passed to the webpage via cookies which works nicely, however then, I can't connect to the firestore database properly.

Here is how I attempt to connect on the HTML page:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "REDACTED",
      authDomain: "REDACTED.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "REDACTED"
    });
    
    var db = firebase.firestore();

    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(cookie_val)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in
      var user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });
```

My rules on the firestore database are below:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /commmunities/{communityId} {
        allow read: if request.resource.community_id == communityId;
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know why/how I should be connecting to the firestore database with a custom token. I have rigorously read the Google documentation and I'm struggling to comprehend them.

**EDIT:**

This project is being run on a website, and here is the code to login with the custom token:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <title>PROFILE SYSTEM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>PROFILE PRESENCE LOADER</h1>
    

    <h1 id="id01">OLD CONTENT</h1>
    
    <script>
    let cname = "CUSTOM TOKEN";
    let name = cname + "=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    console.log(decodedCookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
      let c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        cookie_val = c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        console.log(cookie_val);
      }
    }
      // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "myapikey",
      authDomain: "redacted.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "redacter"
    });
    
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    
    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(cookie_val)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      console.log("SIGNED IN");
      var user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
    });

   

    
    
    </script>
```

The cookie that is collected in the script above, is generated in the flask webserver and is set as a cookie here:

```
uid = f'{newid}'
          additional_claims = {
            'community_id': 231231
          }

          custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(uid, additional_claims)
          
          resp = make_response(redirect('/client'))
          resp.set_cookie('CUSTOM TOKEN', f'{custom_token}')
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? You don't have to do anything once the user logs in with custom token. Also try changing the rule to `allow read: if resource.data.community_id == communityId;` if you are trying to read community_id from the document being accessed.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that in the console on the html webpage of my site, it is telling me it an invalid token!

Comment: Oh so invalid token in `signInWithCustomToken()`? Can you share complete code so we can see where `cookie_val` is coming from ?

Comment: In fact, ill just edit my post above..

Comment: @Dharmaraj cookie_val is a cookie im setting in the flask webserver, this cookie is generated using the official structure - edited main post to include...